# how to check if the click is Performclick or not

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Hi i have a requirement to check for a button click is a performclick or not .
some thing like 
if(click is button1.performclick())
{do something }
else
{do something }

can any one help

Answer (score 2):

Check the event args of the Click event.

When you click the button itself; the event args contain the coordinates of the mouse.
When PerformClick was executed; the event args are empty.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If e.Equals(EventArgs.Empty) Then
        ' Performclick
    Else
        ' Normal click
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
```