# button clicked by performClick() or click on display android

Tags: android, button, onclick

My Android app shows a floorplan, on which transparent Buttons are set on specific areas. I also implemented a Voice Recognition, that returns a Listview. When the user chooses one item the performClick() Method is performed, which calls the OnClick method. The OnClick method is also called, when the user clicks on the specific area on the display (transparent button)

My question is, how can I see, if the Button is clicked by performClick() or by click on the display?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    });


wordsList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Object o = wordsList.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String pen = o.toString();
                    if (pen.equals("String")) {
                        button.performClick();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen: " + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

I already found that post, but I don't know how to implement this in Java.
[how to check if the click is Performclick or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821893/how-to-check-if-the-click-is-performclick-or-not)

Comment: you can check the id of the clicked view

Comment: I would be using simple flag to distinguish. Before calling performClick I will enable the flag. In onclick listener if it is true toggle the flag then perfrom the task

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it is so easy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question. Surely I thought there must be a built-in return method of some sort that could tell us whether or not a click was performed by the actual onClick() method or by performClick() but after a while of searching I instead decided to make my own solution...

In the class that perform clicked is called create:

```
public static boolean performClicked;
```

In your method that calls "performClick()" simply change 
     performClicked = true;
right before the call to perform click.

in your onClick use a similar if statement:

```
if (performClicked){
  performClicked = false;
 //DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO WITH THIS INFO
 }
```

I know this is kind of an obvious answer, but maybe not.